# Computing Maximum Likelihood and Least Squares Estimators for Parameter Estimation of Gaussian Model

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, least-squares, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I am having trouble with the following question, particularly the first part. 
Doesn't least squares require that errors be the same across the RV drawn from a distribution. However the variance changes for each RV though it is some fixed value. Could someone show me how to do this problem:

Let $ X_j \sim N(j\mu, j^3\sigma^2) $ be independent random variables j = 1,...,n where $\mu $ is the unknown parameter and $\sigma^2 >0 $ is some known fixed value.

Compute:
(a) $\hat{\mu_1}$, the (unweighted) least squares estimator for $\mu$ 
(b) $\hat{\mu_2}$, the maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$

Comment: Your model is $X_j=j\mu+\varepsilon_j$, where $\varepsilon_j \sim N(0,j^3\sigma^2)$ are independent. You are to find the least square estimator by minimising the error sum of squares. That is all you have to worry about for part (a).